# What is the most performant way to retrieve time in *nix in C++/boost?

Tags: c++, unix, boost

I know this question has too many variables to have a single answer, but would appreciate your help in understanding what the options are.

My application needs to receive a very large number of events from network and needs to "stamp" each message with the time of arrival at least at milliseconds resolution, to perform later a number of calculations based on those timestamps.

My past experience tells me that getting clock time at a high rate is a performance killer, as they translate to system/kernel calls. Are there "lesser worst options" in a Unix environment in C++ ?

As a starting point I'm using now "boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()"

, which goes to microsec resolution (which I don't need) and that gives me an absolute time (where in principle I would be ok with a relative offset to any epoch).

What are my best alternatives ?

Comment: Any problem with `time(NULL)`?

Comment: You have any code samples/measures at hand, to improve your assumptions?

Comment: @Havenard `time(2)` is in seconds. The question specifies millisecond resolution.

Comment: If your UNIX system runs on CPUs with clock registers (e.g. x86 RDTSCP) then that would be the fastest option (but for the TSC example it's non-trivial to do correctly across cores and has several caveats re wrapping, variable clocks, suspend...).  Note that having a function nominally returns microseconds does not mean you have microsecond precision - the readings may well jump by some number of microseconds each time... you can measure by spinning calling the function and recording the smallest positive delta between successive readings.  Same for any other apparent precision.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say which is faster, but have you thought about exactly what kind of time you need?

- `clock(3)`: CPU ticks… useful for performance testing, but not timing network calls or timestamps.
- `clock_gettime(3)` `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`: [Unalterable time](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime)… useful for [timing network calls](https://blog.habets.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time).
- `gettimeofday(2)`: Wall time… useful for timestamps and maybe performance testing.

Make sure whatever time method you pick suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The following gets you timestamps in microsecond (which you say is too much for you).
it is easy to adjust division/multiplications to get you microseconds:

```
const uint32_t getTime()
{

    struct timeval  tv;
    struct timezone tz;
    struct tm      *tm;

    gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
    tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);

    return (tm->tm_hour * 3600000000/*3600 * 1000 * 1000*/) +
    (tm->tm_min * 60000000/*60 * 1000 * 1000*/) +
    (tm->tm_sec * 1000000/*1000 * 1000*/) +
    (tv.tv_usec);
}
```